# Calculate algorithm execution time and it's functions superior and inferior limit. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, function, time-complexity

I have a very basic question about the calculation of algorithm execution time and its superior and inferior limits.

I have this bubble sort function:

```
def organise(arr):
    change = True
    while change:
        change = False
        for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
            if arr[i] > arr[i + 1]:
                arr[i], arr[i + 1] = arr[i + 1], arr[i]
                change = True
```

I know that it's time complexity in the worst case analysis is n(n-1) = O(n^2) , as the while loop will run at least once and the for loop will run n-1 time.

**How can I get the functions that will represent it´s superior and inferior limits?**

I will then like to represent it graphically with matplotlib plot to be able to see it in a graph.

In my analisis the steps are:

```
1 value assignation to the variable swapped  
While loop that will run n times 
    1 value assignation to the variable swapped  
    For every element in the array minus one time 
        Find the element 
        Compare the element 
        Assign values to the elements 
        Assign a value
```

And from this steps counted I get the equation  1 + n * 4(n-1) = 1 + 4(n^2-1) = n^2

I am lost with finding functions that will represent the inferior and superior limit for this time function.

I guess I do not quite understand the concept, is it that the limits are represented by the best case in which the array is already swapped and therefore there will be no need for the assignations to compute O(n)? If so, the superior limit is the function  is x + n^2?

I will really appreciate any hint (:

Answer (score 0):

The worst and best case analysis consists of identifying how for a specific length of the input list the number of iterations is still influenced by the actual data in that list.

We can see that the number of iterations of the inner loop (`for`) does *not* depend on the data, only on the size of the list -- let's call that size .

But the number of iterations of the outer loop (`while`) depends on the boolean `change`, which in turn depends on whether `arr[i] > arr[i + 1]` was true or not after the execution of the inner loop. *That does depend on the data*.

So then the worst case happens when `change` becomes `True` as often as possible.

The best case happens when `change` never becomes `True` on the first time that the inner loop completes. Because then the outer loop will only iterate once.

Let's look at some extreme lists of size :

1. An input list that is sorted in reversed order (descending).

   In this case the inner loop will find its inner `if` condition `True` on its first iteration repeatedly (try it on a piece of paper).

   On the first iteration of the outer loop, *one* value (located at `arr[0]`) will bubble all the way up (to the right) to its final destination spot, i.e. at the far right. The next iteration of the outer loop will do the same with the value that then is located at `arr[0]` -- which is the second greatest value -- and bubble it to the one-but-last position. And so the outer loop will iterate  times, where in the (-1)<sup>th</sup> iteration `arr[0]` will swap with `arr[1]`, and the list will be sorted. All the remaining iterations of the inner `for` loop will find the `if` condition is `False`. The outer loop will iterate once more only to find that there is nothing to swap, and so `change` remains `False`.

   This means that when the input is sorted in descending order, there will be ² executions of the inner `if` in total, and so we have a time complexity of O(²) in the worst case.

   The way you reasoned was:

   > ...as the while loop will run at least once and the for loop will run n-1 time.

   But this is not convincing. We must really have a case where we have proof that the outer loop executes O() times, not just once. Only when it executes O() times do we conclude that the time complexity is O(²).
2. An input list that is already sorted (ascending).

   In this case the inner loop will not find the `if` condition to be ever `True`, and so `change` remains `False` and the outer loop exits after its first and only iteration.

   This means that the inner `if` statement only executes  times, and so the best case is O().

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! What I wanted to understand though, is how to get the superior and inferior limit of the function O(n^2)

Comment: O(n²) is not a function. Not sure what you mean?

Comment: Big O is a notation that gives an upper limit to a function. Big Omega is a notation that gives a lower limit for a function. The function in this case is the execution time of your algorithm. So for your algorithm the upper bound is O(²) and the lower bound is Ω()